# Neural Network POC limited output range

Tags: neural-network

To keep this as brief as possible, I have implemented a Neural Network in Java that originally was written as just an example of XOR.

This works great, so I moved on to a proof of concept on loading up the input's/output's of the NN.  I've changed the algorithm to take in binary and read what number its suppose to be seeing.  with 2 bits, or 3 bits as the input, I can get great results with the expected output.

```
-- --> 0.000
-O --> 1.000
O- --> 2.000
OO --> 3.000
```

and

```
--- --> 0.000
--O --> 1.000
-O- --> 2.000
-OO --> 3.000
O-- --> 4.000
O-O --> 5.000
OO- --> 6.000
OOO --> 7.000
```

Now, once I increase the bits input / output expected number to 4, I begin to run into problems.

```
---- --> 0.985
---O --> 0.985
--O- --> 3.160
--OO --> 3.160
-O-- --> 4.990
-O-O --> 4.990
-OO- --> 6.747
-OOO --> 6.747
O--- --> 8.094
O--O --> 8.094
O-O- --> 9.696
O-OO --> 9.696
OO-- --> 12.531
OO-O --> 12.531
OOO- --> 14.395
OOOO --> 14.395
```

What is the conceptual reason for this to occur?  I have tried all types of hidden layer sizes and layer numbers with no difference in results.

I will output one more larger result.

```
----- --> 2.515
----O --> 2.515
---O- --> 2.515
---OO --> 2.515
--O-- --> 6.598
--O-O --> 6.598
--OO- --> 6.598
--OOO --> 6.598
-O--- --> 10.241
-O--O --> 10.241
-O-O- --> 10.241
-O-OO --> 10.241
-OO-- --> 14.364
-OO-O --> 14.364
-OOO- --> 14.364
-OOOO --> 14.364
O---- --> 18.190
O---O --> 18.190
O--O- --> 18.190
O--OO --> 18.190
O-O-- --> 22.319
O-O-O --> 22.319
O-OO- --> 22.319
O-OOO --> 22.319
OO--- --> 26.824
OO--O --> 26.824
OO-O- --> 26.824
OO-OO --> 26.824
OOO-- --> 30.966
OOO-O --> 30.966
OOOO- --> 30.966
OOOOO --> 30.966
```

As you can see, its possible to calculate the apparent "bunching" going on.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer came down to the number of bits in my response.  Long story short,  if you are using 1 output neuron for an integer expected output, the data type's number of bits is the output range...

**The fix is output neuron return type's number of bits (Float 32, Double 64) is the range you should not exceed.**

For my training set's expected results, I just ran a conversion of **numberYouWant/maxNumberTheResultYouWantTheNetworkToBe * outputsDataSize**

Basically, get it to count to 32 or 64 really well, and make any number system fit into that.

Thanks for no help :)